# Single ListView Adapter to serve different data to single ListView

Tags: android, listview, android-listview

I have my own custom ListView adapter which gets say for example 100 records. Now, out of these 100 records I want to show only select records in ListView. These select records could be in random order.

I have four such buttons and every time I click button I want to populate different records from adapter without making a new request again.

Any idea how can I achieve this?

Comment: put some code to get help..

Comment: You should alter data source (e.g. ArrayList) used by adapter and notifyDataChange();

Comment: That would be difficult for me as I am using very generic Custom adapter which uses LruCache and adapter being used at multiple places. What about filtering at getView?

Comment: it is not good way to filter at getView()

Comment: i did this before ,so you should categorize the records according to your buttons and when a particular button clicked you have to set the new data source for it.thats it.. !

Comment: @KailashDabhi new data source means? data source is already populated with all the mixed data in first connection.

Comment: you make the separate arraylist for each button and when particular button clicked you set that arraylist which has been created in constructor.. do you get my point?

Answer (score 0):

Make two lists inside your custom adapter. 
One - with all your records. And one - with records, that you want to display.

On click, you fill second list with data from first list somehow, call notifyDataSetChanged(). On other click, clear that list, fill with another records, and call notifyDataSetChanged() again.